# Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld ........failed

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

On my rpi I am trying to create image with mysql server. It fails..

Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/debian:10
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y default-mysql-server
RUN service mysql restart
```

OUTPUT:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

So I changed Dockerfile to:

```
FROM arm32v7/debian:10
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y default-mysql-server
RUN touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
RUN touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
RUN chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
RUN chmod -R 644 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
RUN service mysql restart
```

OUTPUT:

```
 ...
Stopping MariaDB database server: mysqld.
Starting MariaDB database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
The command '/bin/sh -c service mysql restart' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I runned image with `docker run -it <IMAGE_ID> bash` 
I restarted mysql service again with the same output.
I checked `service mysql status`

OUTPUT:

```
[info] MariaDB is stopped..
```

I checked `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. This file is empty.

I have no idea what to do

Comment: why not to use the official mysql image ?

Comment: official mysql image does not support arm architecture.

Comment: https://github.com/arm32v7/mysql

Comment: Docker images don’t include running processes, so `RUN service start ...` is really a no-op; in the worst case it will leave behind a pid file that will stop the actual container process from running.  You need to launch the service directly as a foreground process as the `CMD`, which won’t involve commands like `service`.

Comment: I have same problem on https://github.com/VitexSoftware/BuildImages/blob/main/Buster/Dockerfile (AMD64) :(